# Python script called by webserver does not execute web request

Tags: python, php

I'm new to webservers and was experimenting a little. Currently my workflow is:
Nginx Server serving index.html -> Hands over input to PHP script -> PHP script hands over input to python script and executes it via shell_exec -> result shall be echoed to webpage.

This works fine for any Python script not issuing web request, but just prints stuff. However, I'd like my Python script to make use of an API from another webserver and provide that output to the user. The execution of the python script works fine from command line and so does the php script, which let's me believe I'm missing something on the nginx configuration.

Addendum:

The Python script is using OpenAI's API to interact with one of their models. As mentioned before, it works fine on CLI when being called by the php script, as well as being directly executed with python interpreter, but not when hosted & called through webserver:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3



import os

import openai

import sys


openai.api_key = "somekey"

result = openai.Completion.create(

  model="text-davinci-003",

  prompt=str(sys.argv[1]),

  max_tokens=2048,

  temperature=0

)

print(result)
```

The PHP script is:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {

  // collect value of input field

  $input = $_REQUEST['input'];

  if (empty($input)) {

    echo "Input is empty";

  } else {


    $escaped_input = escapeshellarg($input);

    // command to be executed

    $command = 'python3 /var/www/html/davinci.py ' . $escaped_input;

    // execute the command

    $output = shell_exec($command);

    // display output

    echo $output;

  }

//}

?>
```

Things I tried so far:

1. I inserted print statements right before and after the web requests but none of them is being shown. It appears the script is not even called. Every other non web requesting script (e.g. printing the provided input) works.
2. Set execution permissions to all files involved.
3. Increased Max Time Out in PHP config
4. Added header add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *; to http section in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: Could upload your Python Script? Have no idea about the issue without code.

Comment: Is this a Python problem, a nginx problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: I think its a webserver problem.  Perhaps python is not installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need python to handle stuff, than you might consider getting rid of the nginx and the PHP components, and implement your webservice with python only.

In order to achieve this, there is the [Tornado Web Server](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) you can use to handle HTTP requests and execute the pyhton scripts.